# Identifying which text fields were modified in Vaadin

Tags: java, javabeans, textfield, vaadin

I have a table with a data source that is a `BeanItemContainer`.

When a user selects a row in the table the corresponding columns fill a group of `TextFields` so that the user can edit the information.  What I am trying to do is find out a clean approach to identifying which `Fields` were edited once the user **clicks save** (*so that I keep track of what changes were made by a user, and so that I only save what is necessary*).

I have seen that I can use `isModified()` to see if a `Field` has changed from its previous value, but calling this for every `TextField` seems to much (*also `isModified()` does not seem to work when I call it on a textfield*).  So I am basically looking for a **better approach** for checking to see if a field has been modified.

Thank you

Comment: just as a hint: when you use an ORM framework like hibernate or eclipselink, they care about saving changed values.

Comment: I am looking into hibernate envers, but would also like to know if vaadin has its own way of doing it (or maybe GWT).

Answer (score 0):

When you create TextFields put the current Property value (String) in the TextField:

```
tf.setData(property.getValue())
```

When the user clicks save you can compare the two values (the current and the saved).

Answer (score 0):

Use BeanItem properties. You have to compare values yourself but you do it in a loop for each property (See method "between" in source code down). All you need is data class that can be used as BeanItem, or is BeanItem itself. In UI you need to have object with original data and object with original data with changes. Here is class I use to extract changes between two versions of data:

```
public class Diff implements Iterable<DiffEntry>{

public static class DiffEntry{
    public final Object propertyId;
    public final Object oldValue;
    public final Object newValue;

    public DiffEntry(Object propertyId, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
        super();
        this.propertyId = propertyId;
        this.oldValue = oldValue;
        this.newValue = newValue;
    }
}

public static <T> Diff between(T oldPojo, T newPojo) {
    //HERE WE EXTRACT WHAT WAS CHANGED
    // this could also take BeanItems directly if data are BeanItems
    Diff diff = new Diff();
    BeanItem<T> oldBean = new BeanItem<T>(oldPojo);
    BeanItem<T> newBean = new BeanItem<T>(newPojo);
    for(Object propertyId : oldBean.getItemPropertyIds()) {
        Object oldValue = oldBean.getItemProperty(propertyId).getValue();
        Object newValue = newBean.getItemProperty(propertyId).getValue();
        if(oldValue == null) {
            if(newValue != null) {
                DiffEntry entry = new DiffEntry(propertyId, oldValue, newValue);
                diff.add(entry);
            }
        }
        else if(newValue == null) {
            DiffEntry entry = new DiffEntry(propertyId, oldValue, newValue);
            diff.add(entry);
        }
        else if(!oldValue.equals(newValue)) {
            DiffEntry entry = new DiffEntry(propertyId, oldValue, newValue);
            diff.add(entry);
        }
        else {
            //old and new values are equal
        }
    }
    return diff;
}

private final Map<Object, DiffEntry> entries = new HashMap<>();

public Diff() {

}

private void add(DiffEntry entry) {
    this.entries.put(entry.propertyId, entry);
}

/**
 * Returns true if this diff contains difference for specified property id
 * @param propertyId id of property we test for difference
 * @return true if this diff contains difference for specified property id
 */
public boolean contains(Object propertyId) {
    return this.entries.containsKey(propertyId);
}

/**
 * Returns true if there are no differencies
 * @return true if there are no differencies
 */
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return this.entries.isEmpty();
}

@Override
public Iterator<DiffEntry> iterator() {
    return entries.values().iterator();
}
}
```

In the context of yours *"keep track of what changes were made by a user, and only save what is necessary"* this will do the job, but it does not prevent processing all fields from UI, since this is done after all data are read from fields and stored in *newPojo* !